# DetailsView can't get its values that are inside the LoginView

Tags: asp.net, webforms, detailsview, loginview

I've a parent DetailsView control, and in the `InsertTemplate` I have a `LoginView` that prevent non-logged-in users from inserting.

When catching the values in the `DetailsView_Inserting` event, All Values are null!

```
e.Values["title"] = Server.HtmlEncode(e.Values["title"].ToString());
```

The `e.Values["title"]` in the right side is null

The problem started when I added the `LoginView` control.

I think I can solve it by finding controls manually, but is there a trick way to resolve the control from finding his values?

The markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dtlContent" ...........>
<Fields>
<asp:TemplateField>
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ID="loginView">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
         <p>You should login first!</p>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox Width="100%" ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'></asp:TextBox>

        </tr>
        </table>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
</InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the FindControl:

```
TextBox TXTtitle= (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("txtTitle");
```